# "Prototype mismatch" warning with Test2::Mock

Tags: unit-testing, perl, warnings

Running the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.038;

use Test2::Mock;
use Time::HiRes;

my($mock) = Test2::Mock->new(
    class => 'Time::HiRes',
    override => [
        gettimeofday => sub { return 1; },
    ]
);

my($foo) = Time::HiRes::gettimeofday;
say $foo;
```

results in this output:

```
Prototype mismatch: sub Time::HiRes::gettimeofday () vs none at /opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.38.0/Test2/Mock.pm line 434.
1
Prototype mismatch: sub Time::HiRes::gettimeofday: none vs () at /opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.38.0/Test2/Mock.pm line 452.
```

I don't know how to get rid of the prototype mismatch warnings. I've tried a number of things with no effect (some of them out of desperation, not because I thought they would work):

- adding a prototype to the anon sub

```
gettimeofday => sub () { return 1; },
```

- defined a named sub with a prototype in a `BEGIN` block & used it instead

```
BEGIN {
    sub gtod () { return 1; }
}

my($mock) = Test2::Mock->new(
    class => 'Time::HiRes',
    override => [
        gettimeofday => \&gtod,
    ]
);
```

- using `Time::Hires` before `Test2::Mock`
- imported `gettimeofday` into `main` and overrode that, in combination with all of the above, e.g.:

```
use Test2::Mock;
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);

my($mock) = Test2::Mock->new(
    class => 'main',
    override => [
        gettimeofday => sub () { return 1; },
    ]
);

my($foo) = gettimeofday;
say $foo;
```

- wrapped it in a `no warnings 'prototype'` block

```
{
    no warnings 'prototype';

    my($mock) = Test2::Mock->new(
        class => 'main',
        override => [
            gettimeofday => sub () { return 1; },
        ]
    );
}
```

Nothing made any difference.

My code works, but there's a warning for a reason, and I'd really like to deal with it in the proper manner. The best I've come up with Googling for an answer is to suppress the message by modifying `$SIG{__WARN__}`, which just seems like a bad idea, if there are other options.

Note: I am aware of [`Test::Mock::Time`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Mock::Time), [`Test::MockTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockTime), and [`Test::MockTime::HiRes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockTime::HiRes) -- they don't do what I need them to do, so I thought I'd roll my own. Also, I've looked at [`Sub::Prototype`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Prototype) but haven't tried it, yet, as it's not a core module and I'd rather not go there unless there's no other choice (at which point I may modify `$SIG{__WARN__}` instead.

Comment: Sub declarations already happen at compile-time. The BEGIN block has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `signatures` feature is enabled, `()` is not a prototype but a signature.

You are enabling this feature using `use 5.038;`.

The fix is to use

```
sub :prototype() { return 1; }
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the classic prototype syntax (`sub() { return 1; }`) in a section of code where the `signatures` feature is disabled (e.g. using `no feature qw( signatures );`).